# How to copy authorized_keys to another user on linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora

I can ssh into a Linux node on the cloud with root.  I've created another user, web, and I want to add my ssh keys to that user.  Here's what I've tried so far (as root):

```
mkdir -p /home/web/.ssh
cp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/web/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown web /home/web/.ssh
chgrp web /home/web/.ssh
chown -R :web /home/web/.ssh
chmod -R g+w /home/web/.ssh
find /home/web/.ssh -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \;
systemctl reload sshd
```

I'm pretty sure I'm over-setting the permissions but regardless I still can't ssh into the server as the web user.  Box is Fedora 21 on Digital Ocean.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's an entire wiki on SSH here:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info

It has troubleshooting tips for when stuff isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Your permissions are too lax.

```
chmod u=rwx,go= .ssh    # 0700
chmod u=rw,go= .ssh/*   # 0600
```

I'm going to assume that the user/group you have specified are the correct values for whatever uses /home/web as its home directory.

To diagnose this kind of error it's best to look at the daemon/auth logs on the server. See the tag [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) here for more details.

Comment: As root I set the permissions for /home/web/.ssh and /home/web/.ssh/* as you suggested.  My /var/log/daemon.log and /var/log/auth.log are both non-existant, and ssh -vvv doesn't seem to be a valid option or run anything.  I've read through the info here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info and tried everything listed as well but still can't ssh in as web.  Any further ideas?

Comment: For Fedora the security logs are apparently in `/var/log/secure`. Take a look to see why `ssh` is objecting to your login attempt.